# How to use factory const constructors?

Tags: constructor, dart, constants, factory

To test my understanding of Dart, I made a 2D immutable vector that stores not only its x and y components, but also its angle and length. They are computed only at construction out of the x and y values. I soon realized that final fields need to be set with initializer lists or the `this`-parameter shortcut, which don't allow for much computed values. Like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29137214/2813263) points out, I had to use a factory constructor to create my vector out of its x and y components. The factory constructor then validates input and computes the length and angle before calling the private constructor.

```
import 'dart:math';

class ImmutableVector {

  // private fields
  final double _x;
  final double _y;
  final double _angle;
  final double _length;

  // getters
  double get x => _x;
  double get y => _y;
  double get angle => _angle;
  double get length => _length;

  /// Constructs a vector out of cartesian components.
  /// 
  /// Converts both arguments to doubles.
  /// Null values will be treated as zeroes.
  factory ImmutableVector.xy(num x, num y) {

    x ??= 0.0;
    y ??= 0.0;
    x = x.toDouble();
    y = y.toDouble();
    var angle = atan2(y, x) % (2*PI);
    var length = sqrt(pow(x, 2) + pow(y, 2));

    return new ImmutableVector._raw(x, y, angle, length);
  }

  /// Constructs a vector by setting the fields directly.
  const ImmutableVector._raw(this._x, this._y, this._angle, this._length);
}
```

But it came to my attention that I could not make the factory constructor const, because const factories can only be redirecting constructors. Is there absolutely no way to make my vector have code in its constructor and still have it an immutable with const constructors? And if so, why?

I'll also mention that I used to throw errors if the values passed were null, but I made it default to zero so I could actually use initializer lists. I then tried to do this, and turns out it works when the constructor isn't a factory:

```
ImmutableVector.xy(num x, num y) : this._raw(
       x = (x ?? 0.0).toDouble(),
       y = (y ?? 0.0).toDouble(),
       atan2(y, x) % (2*PI),
       sqrt(pow(x, 2) + pow(y, 2)));
```

But as soon as I try to make it const, it tells me that the code in the initializer list contains non-compile-time constants.

The only immutable vector I could find in dart was [here on GitHub](https://github.com/bisrael/Phart/blob/master/Vector.dart), and it doesn't do any kind of null-validation or computation on constructor parameters, relying entirely on the fact that methods will break at some point on null-vectors. It also has a constructor that creates a unit vector out of another one with poor performance and repetition thanks to the obligatory initializer list:

```
const Vector.unit(final num x, final num y, final num z) : 
    this(x / PMath.len(x, y, z), y / PMath.len(x, y, z), z / PMath.len(x, y, z));
```

So what should be my conclusion? Did I miss a feature that makes this possible, or should I just give up on using const for this class?

Comment: Warning for newcomers to dart: const in C++ = immutability guarantee. const in JS = constant reference. const in dart = compile-time optimization.

Answer (score 5):

Dart doesn't execute Dart code during compilation. This is the reason `const` constructors can't have a body and why there is no other way to work around this limitation.

If you want to execute code when an instance is created, just don't make use of `const`. Const isn't that important in Dart anyway. There were even discussions to remove it from the language because the benefits are not big enough.

Comment: I thought so. In that case, I'll just get rid of const, making my class less robust doesn't seem like the logical thing to do.

Comment: If you are trying to make the instances immutable, the class does not need to be const, just have no means to modify it's data fields.

Comment: Yeah, I'm aware of that, I just thought it would be nice to optimize with const. But I'm probably trying to optimize too early, I should make a game now instead :)

Comment: Now in 2020, I want to confirm the importance const in Flutter. I've seen heavy usage of const and it appears to be important for performance optimization. Is this true?

Comment: `const` is considered to lead to better performance, but not long ago there was a discussion and not much evidence (benchmarks) could be found. As usual performance strongly depends on your concrete situation. If you have a complex application where this actually matters, make sure you do proper benchmarking yourself to ensure you are optimizing for the right thing with the right measures.

Comment: @Günter Zöchbauer "Const isn't that important in Dart anyway. There were even discussions to remove it from the language because the benefits are not big enough" - The winds change quickly in silicon valley ;D